# Stable Django-Haystack + elasticsearch setup

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, pyelasticsearch

I'm wondering what the best combination of Django-Haystack + elasticsearch + pyelasticsearch/elasticsearch-py is.  I've deployed a setup using Haystack 2.1.1-dev + elasticsearch 1.1.1 + elasticsearch-py 1.0 on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine.  I tried using Haystack 2.1.0 (latest stable release) with elasticsearch 1.1.1 and pyelasticsearch 0.6.1, but it kept throwing me an error saying Django-Haystack depends on pyelasticsearch; so I switched to 2.1.1-dev, which worked beautifully.

But now I'm trying deploy an instance of a Django app to a CentOS 6.5 machine (Haystack 2.1.1-dev + elasticsearch 1.1.1 + elasticsearch-py 1.0), and I'm getting the same pyelasticsearch dependency error.

Any hints or tips from someone who has deployed to CentOS would be much appreciated.

Comment: Either downgrading to around 2.1 or installing 2.4 from git solved the problem; default pip version still broken for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, seemed to be a SELinux error, fixed with:

```
# setenforce 0
```

For reference, we have these packages installed in a virtualenv:

```
-e git://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git@366e7489169d460d36ac4d942c22c0e97e58c26b#egg=django_haystack-master
elasticsearch==1.0.0
```

And elasticsearch-1.1.1-1.noarch through yum on CentOS 6

Edit: The more general fix that doesn't broadly disable SELinux:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```