# haystack.exceptions.MissingDependency: The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the installation of 'elasticsearch'

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, pyelasticsearch

I am newbie to Django-haystack. I got an error while following Django-Haystack documentation.

Command execution order, I followed:

1. I started elasticsearch server (1.7.3) using command prompt and I am able to access http://127.0.0.1:9200/
2. python manage.py rebuild_index

***Output:***

WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

**Error:**

packages\haystack\backends\elasticsearch_backend.py", line 28, in 
    raise MissingDependency("The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the  installation of 'elasticsearch'. Please refer to the documentation.")

**haystack.exceptions.MissingDependency: The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the installation of 'elasticsearch'. Please refer to the documentation.**

**Current Platform (Windows):** 
1. Django 1.8
2. elasticsearch: 1.9.0 (installed through pip)
3. pyelasticsearch: 0.0.5 (installed through pip)
4. elasticseach: 1.7.3 (downloaded to start elasticsearch server)

I have tried adding the 'elasticsearch' also to my installed apps but the same error exists.

It seems there is version compatibility problems (perhaps in pyelasticseach) as I found some others also faced the same issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
Django==1.8.5
django-haystack==2.4.0
djangorestframework==3.2.3
easy-thumbnails==2.2
elasticsearch==1.9.0
elasticsearch-curator==3.3.0
enum34==1.0.4
gevent==1.0.2
gevent-socketio==0.3.5rc2
gevent-websocket==0.9.5
greenlet==0.4.9
idna==2.0
MySQL-python==1.2.5
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.0
nltk==3.0.5
numpy==1.6.1
Pillow==2.9.0
pusher==1.2.3
pyasn1==0.1.8
pycparser==2.14
pyelasticsearch==0.0.5
PyMySQL==0.6.6
pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
requests==2.8.1
simplejson==3.8.0
six==1.10.0
urllib3==1.12

Comment: I have tried installing other versions of pyelasticsearch but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you able to track the issue. Please reply.

Comment: I'm stumped - can't see why it still fails.

Comment: I'm not sure that need both `elasticsearch 1.9.0` and `pyelasticsearch 0.0.5`. Just plain elasticsearch is the 'official' module, while pyelasticsearch is an unofficial version that predates the official version, if that makes sense. Your pyelasticsearch is also quite old, the most up-to-date version being 1.4. Try uninstalling it perhaps?

Comment: I tracked down the issue. The problem was with Haystack version.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257502/cant-get-elasticsearch-working-with-django